# Rechargeable Gameboy Color modification

Tags: voltage, resistors, diodes

I've been doing a little research online on how to make my Gameboy Color rechargeable, and I came across an instructable this guy made on how to make your GBC rechargeable using standard rechargeable batteries.

I wanted to verify that this mod would be safe and also ask, what kind of diode should I use along with the \$1\Omega\$ resistor that he used? I'm including the link to his page below.

http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=22&threadid=122549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a schematic or more data about the gameboy circuits it is not possible to say if it is absolutely safe.

From the images on that page the resistor seems \$1\Omega\$ 1W, while the diode seems a jellybean 3A rectifier, like the [1N5408](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/1N/1N5404.pdf) or similar.

**EDIT**
(following the OP posting a link to the schematic)

I don't see any particular issue, save the possibility of overheating. The charger circuit is extremely rudimentary (a diode with a limiting resistor in series). Assuming the rechargeable cells are of NiMH type, they would require at least a constant current recharging circuit (sophisticated chargers also monitor the voltage and the temperature of the cell during charging). The cells could be well run the risk of being overcharged and get damaged. During charging you should watch out for any excessive temperature rise of the cells. Moreover, never leave the GBC under charge unattended.

Make sure that the cells' chemistry IS NOT lithium-based (I don't think it is, but you never know). Overcharging lithium-based accumulators is ***very dangerous***, they may explode and take fire!

Comment: Link to full Gameboy Color schematics. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8652569/blog/gameboy/CGB%20Service%20Manual.pdf

Comment: Would including a heatsink be a good idea to prevent overheating?

Comment: @JackHaggett No. Heatsinking would simply be a palliative remedy. The problem is that once the cells are charged, they *will* overheat. The problem is that the chemical compounds inside the cells won't be able to "accumulate" more energy, therefore every ampere pumped into the cell *will* be converted to heat (and this will shorten the cells' life in the long run)....

Comment: ... If the current is small compared to the overall cell capacity (say <0.01C, where C is the capacity in amp-hours, for example <10mA for a 1000mAh cell), probably the overheating won't be a big issue (won't make the cell leak or burst), so you could leave the charger connected for a couple of hours or maybe the whole night without too much risk (besides shortening cells' life). Anyway you should do some testing and see if the cells heat up too much: if the cells are so hot that it's uncomfortable to touch them, that's a very bad sign.